# Regex to convert kbt-y102_9999_0001v-s001v => N1v-s1v

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a Regex that converts a string like

> kbt-y102_9999_0001v-s001v

into  `N1v-s1v`

```
kbt-y102_ => ignore everything until first underscore
9999 => N
_0001v => 1v
-s001v => -s1v

kbt-y102_9999_0001v-s001r => N1v-s1r 
kbt-y102_9999_0002r-s001v => N2r-s1v
```

my attempt: `_(9{4})_?(.*)(-s)0+(\d)` ([regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/oxrhLW/1/))

Comment: Why is your attempt not working?

Comment: How can I replace the 9999 with "N"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture `1v` and `1r` in a group and replace with:

`N$1-S$2`

[`[^_]+_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{3}([0-9][vr])-s0+([0-9][vr])`](https://regex101.com/r/Tu7D5g/2)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PFVdu)

Comment: Awesome! But how can I get only "N1v-s1r" instead of "kbt-y102N1v-S1r"?

Comment: You could use preg_replace. I have updated my answer with a demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to modify your regex to get the result with regex only: https://regex101.com/r/Tu7D5g/1