# regex to match kbt-y102_9999_0001v-s001r and kbt-y102_999a

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a Regex that converts strings like

> kbt-y102_9999_0001v-s001v

into  `N1v-s1v`

and

> kbt-y102_999a

into  `N1a`

```
kbt-y102_ => ignore everything until first underscore
9999 => N
_0001v => 1v
-s001v => -s1v

kbt-y102_9999_0001v-s001r => N1v-s1r 
kbt-y102_9999_0002r-s001v => N2r-s1v
kbt-y102_9999_0001v => N1v
kbt-y102_9999_0002r => N2r
kbt-y102_999a => Na
kbt-y102_999aa => Naa
kbt-y102_9999a => Na
kbt-y102_9999aa => Naa
```

my attempt covers the first four cases: `(.*)_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{3}([0-9][vr])?((-s)0{0,2}+([0-9][vr]))?` ([regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/oxrhLW/3/))

But I'm struggling with `999a`.

Comment: How come `kbt-y102_999a` turns into `N1a`? Do you want to insert `1` if there are 3 digits instead of 4 in the part after `N`? But why `kbt-y102_9999a` should turn into `N1a` then?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good catch! I updated my post

Comment: Is this a duplicate or an extension of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216440/regex-to-convert-kbt-y102-9999-0001v-s001v-n1v-s1v) regarding this topic?

Comment: Not a duplicate, it's an extension. I didn't want to reverse the accepted answer for my previous question (it didn't cover the 9999_0001v or 999a ).

Comment: Try `^[^_]*_9+([a-z]*)(?:_0*([12][a-z])(?:(-[a-z])0*([12][rv]))?)?` Live demo https://regex101.com/r/oxrhLW/5

Comment: @revo awesome, can you provide this as an answer? It works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your patterns this is a general Regular Expression to extract required data:

```
^[^_]*_\d+([a-z]*)(?:_0*([1-9][a-z])(?:(-[a-z])0*([1-9][a-z]))?)?
```

It's long but has nothing more than some acceptable wildcards (tokens) in proper places. You need to replace match with:

```
N$1$2$3$4
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/VUVF0r/1)